# Rails installed SimpleForm but still undefined method `input'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating an "input tag name" field in a form, however, I get an `` undefined method `input' `` error when I execute it. This is confusing, unless I rewrite the input to `text_field` to avoid the error. However, I have installed SimpleForm in Gemfile and this error should not happen. Please tell me what am I missing?

This is part of my Gemfile

```
gem 'select2-rails'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 5.1.3'
gem 'simple_form'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
```

This is the View

```
<%= form_for(task) do |f| %>

    <% if @task.errors.present? %>
      <ol>
       <% @task.errors.each do |error, message| %>
        <li>WARNING: 
          <%= "#{error.capitalize}  #{message}" %>
        </li>
         <% end %>
      </ol>
    <% end %>

      <div>
        <%= f.label :name, t('task_title') %>
          <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>

      <div>
        <%= f.label :due_date, t('task_date') %>
          <%= f.datetime_field :due_date %>
      </div>

      <div>
        <%= f.label :status, t('task_status') %>
        <%= f.select :status, options_for_select(Task.statuses.map { |key, value| [t("checkpoint_status.#{key}"), value] },@task.status)%>
      </div>

      <div>
        <%= f.label :priority, t('task_priority') %>
        <%= f.select :priority, Task.priorities.map { |key, value| [t("checkpoint_priority.#{key}"), key] } %>
      </div>

      <div>
        <%= f.label :note, t('task_cont') %>
        <%= f.text_area :note %>
      </div>

      <div>
        <%= f.label :tag_list, t('task_tag') %>
        <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
        <%= f.button :submit ,class: "btn-outline-primary" %>
      </div>
      
      <div>
        <%= f.submit t('task_save') %>
      </div>

    <% end %>
<p>
<%= link_to t('hp') , list_tasks_path %>
```

Comment: can you show the whole view

Comment: you have to use `simple_form_for` instead of `form_for`.

Answer (score 0):

is this the correct view? you are using `form_for` here, however if you want to use simple form you would need to use `simple_form_for`.
(also make sure not to forget to bundle install)

something like this maybe:

```rb
<%= simple_form_for @some_instance do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :foo %>

  <%= f.submit "submit" %>
<% end %>
```